# Multiple actions for a single form

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have an html homepage which has a form. The form submit button sends the query to a single php page called First.php which gives the necessary data from the database in a tabular format. A single column from the table contains links as the contents of the column are too large to display on the same page. Once the link is selected, it gives the exact column information of only that query which I submitted on the homepage.
My general idea was to give two actions to the form action which can be used on two different pages but that to no result.

Here's the homepage :

```
<form action="First.php" action ="Second.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" size="90" name="search1">
<input type="hidden" size="90" name="search1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search..">
</form>
```

First.php after connecting to database and the firing the sql query :

```
if($ant>0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['A'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['G'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><b href='Second.php'>Link</b></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Please do help me for the Second.php.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You can't have two same name attributes for single tag. Also why you mark your question with `phpmyadmin` tag?

Comment: I thought phpmyadmin extraction to be the correct tag for my question but in any case sorry and thank you for the advise.

Comment: @Srk phpMyAdmin is a tool used to view a MySQL database. Your data is in MySQL, not in phpMyAdmin. Anyway, il seems to me that the way you get your data is not important enough to the question to deserve a tag.

Comment: This question is a bit confused. Note that so far you had 3 answers and each one is making a different assumption about what the question is and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is common pagination problem. You should use extra parameter in your form.

do something like

```
if($ant>0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['A'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['G'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><b href='First.php?page=2'>Link</b></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a second action at all (and you cannot have one). What you need is to pass the id of the row to `Second.php` as a `GET` parameter. If you are not familiar with the concept, look it up because you will need it. A lot.

In `Second.php` you do not need the search parameters anymore because you are showing the details about a single row and you have its id. You just make a query to the DB to retrieve it by id and the old search becomes irrelevant.

In good conscience I have to say that the `mysql_`-something functions are a BAD idea. They have been removed in newer versions of php and are dangerous to use in the old ones. I strongly suggest that you use `PDO` and prepared statements ot at least the `mysqli_` family of functions.